# How to populate KO binded list with items from a cookie array

Tags: javascript, json, cookies, knockout.js

i am building a cookie to temporarily save shopping cart items and trying to populate a knockout list with an array string from my cookie.

But KO doesn't seem to understand that the array in the cookie is an array, nor does it iterate through the array on the table.

when the user clicks on the "add to cart" button this happens:

```
$("#add2cart").click(function() {
function complete() {

//Animation saying added to cart
    $("<div>").text("Added to cart!").appendTo("#log");
    $("#log").show("fast");

  //formats date for db
    var datetime = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " ");

  //gathers cookie data
 var itemsString = $.cookie("cookieCart");
    var items = "";

    if (itemsString === "undefined") {
        itemsString = "";
    } else {
        if (itemsString != null) {
            //parses the cookie array
            items = JSON.parse(itemsString); // unserialize
        } else {
            items = [];
        }
        //UPDATE *I REMOVED THE BRACKETS BECAUSE IT WAS MAKING AN ARRAY OF AN ARRAY*
     var newItem = { datetime: datetime, id: id, typeid: typeid, qty: 1       };
        items.push(newItem); // modify
        $.cookie("cookieCart", JSON.stringify(items), { path: "/" });  //   serialize
    }
}

$("#add2cart").fadeOut(1000, "linear", complete);
});
```

An example of two items pushed into the array:

[[{"datetime":"2016-02-17 14:31:34","id":"749","typeid":"13","qty":1}],[{"datetime":"2016-02-17 14:59:26","id":"756","typeid":"13","qty":1}]]

So now i want to have a table automatically populate with just the datetime of those items. So my ko looks like this:

```
var itemArray = [];
var cartItems = $.cookie("cookieCart");
itemArray = JSON.parse(cartItems); // unserialize

ko.applyBindings({
cartItemArray: cartItems
});
```

and my table looks like this:

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: cartItemArray">
    <tr>
<td data-bind="text: datetime"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

When i run it javascript crashes with

*Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return cartItemArray }"
Message: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return datetime }"
Message: datetime is not defined*

when i change data-bind="text: datetime" to data-bind="text: cartItems"

it gives me :

[[{"datetime":"2016-02-17 14:31:34","id":"749","typeid":"13","qty":1}],[{"datetime":"2016-02-17 14:59:26","id":"756","typeid":"13","qty":1}]]
[[{"datetime":"2016-02-17 14:31:34","id":"749","typeid":"13","qty":1}],[{"datetime":"2016-02-17 14:59:26","id":"756","typeid":"13","qty":1}]]
[[{"datetime":"2016-02-17 14:31:34","id":"749","typeid":"13","qty":1}],
...

(several times)

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: To start with, you shouldn't be using jQuery selectors in your viewmodel code. (Your viewmodel code is everything that isn't a binding handler.) Use Knockout bindings.
Next, it looks like your array is an array-of-array-of-object, and you are treating it like an array-of-object.

Comment: i see now i removed the extra brackets to the push
var newItem = { datetime: datetime, id: id, typeid: typeid, qty: 1 };

Comment: My eyes are hurting just by watching your code... you have KO and yet use 99.9% jQuery code? Dude!!! you just bought a Ferrari and yet you're having a couple of horses in the front for pulling it like an old carriage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was simply because i had extra brackets on the item i was pushing to the array:

```
 var newItem = [{ datetime: datetime, id: id, typeid: typeid, qty: 1}];
```

needed to be

```
 var newItem = {datetime: datetime, id: id, typeid: typeid, qty: 1};
```